# Induced map on $T(X)$ the Tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

If$ f:X\to Y$ is an Immersion\ Submersion\ Diffeomorphism then what can we say about the induced map  $ df: T(X)\to T(Y) $ defined as $df(x,v)= (f(x),df_x(v))$.
 Will it also have the same properties? I don't know how to start, kindly help.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The best way to see this is to look it locally. If $f$ is a diffeomorphism, $f^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism and the inverse of $df$ is $df^{-1}$ defined by $df^{-1}(x,v)=(f^{-1}(x),df^{-1}(v))$.

If $f$ is an immersion submersion and$x\in X$ there exists a chart $U$ containing $x$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $U$ is an immersion/submersion whose image is contained in a chart containing $f(y)$. It is enough to show the result when $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. In this case, immersion submersion are characterized by the constant rank theorem and local diffeomorphism

see

[Local Submersion Theorem - Differential Topology of Guillemin and Pollack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320102/local-submersion-theorem-differential-topology-of-guillemin-and-pollack)

and

[Local Immersion Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793193/local-immersion-theorem-in-mathbbrn-proof)

which reduce the problem to a linear map.

Comment: Study the local situation with the local inversion theorem. Remark that the tangent space of an open subset is a trivial bundle.

Comment: smoothness comes for free in this case.

Comment: But  How, I am talking about the Derivative map , the second argument in the ordered pair of df @AnubhavMukherjee

Comment: Yeah, I know that tangent space of open subset is actually the whole Tangent space. Does this helps with the smoothness of $df_x $@TsemoAristide ?